# Safe practice for commenting a chain of commands?

Tags: bash, command

Is there any safe way to document a long chain of commands with comments for readers which will not pose a risk to my system?

Assuming all of the steps are correct and intentional, pretend I have the following:

```
step 1
step 2
step 3
...
step 76
step 77
- this next step needs to move files to xyz so that dependency ufh will properly resolve
step 78
step 79
...
step 203
- multi-line comment which explains something really long and should be
- manually wrapped for legibility purposes.
- Oh yeah, and it is followed by a list:
- * list item 1
- * list item 2
step 204
...
step 326
- another comment but this time I contain sudo ls / for some unholy reason
step 327
...
step 435
```

I would like to copy it from top to bottom and right-click paste it into a PuTTY session so that the commands execute sequentially but do not execute something unintentional from the comments.

---

Based on comments and answers it seems that it is questionable whether or not I am truly in the bash shell.

```
echo $o
```

produces "-bash"

Comment: What sort of risk are you expecting from your comments?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I do not know what to anticipate. I prefixed my comments with `-` just for purposes of posting this question. Can you think of anything malicious which could result from prefixing with `-`? Is there a "safer" character to use?

Comment: Since you tagged bash, I'll just add a comment: to ensure `shopt interactive_comments` is `on`. (From the manpage: `The interactive_comments option is on by default in interactive shells`, but you'd get errors if it was turned off before pasting the lines)

Comment: Write a shell script and use standard commenting for it.

Comment: Linking in: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39118/how-can-i-protect-myself-from-this-kind-of-clipboard-abuse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a generically unwise thing to do.

If you're using Bash, like the tag suggests, then as long as [`shopt interactive_comments` is on](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin), you can [use actual comments with `#`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Comments). That is enabled by default, but may be disabled in the shell you're using. You could turn that on explicitly at the top:

```
shopt -s interactive_comments
command...
# a comment
more commands...
```

However, if you're concerned about *malicious* actions, **you should never be copying text into the terminal**. The malicious content [could be hidden where you don't see it](http://www.ush.it/team/ascii/hack-tricks_253C_CCC2008/wysinwyc/what_you_see_is_not_what_you_copy.txt) (and [here's a working example to try](https://thejh.net/misc/website-terminal-copy-paste)) - it doesn't have to be in a comment. If you really do have 435 steps, it could be hidden even where you do see it and you're never going to notice.

---

An actual shell script would be better (and comments will definitely work there), but again if it's malice you're worried about you need to review very carefully before you run it. Copying and pasting into the terminal is at best unreliable in any case (as a recurring series of questions on this site shows), and you'd be better off finding a workflow that doesn't rely upon it.

Comment: I think this is the answer I am looking for. `interactive_comments` is turned on in my instance. I definitely see why creating a shell script is a wiser choice. Additionally, my question was asked under the assumption that the steps are all correct and intentional. My main concern was being able to write a comment which contains code not intended for execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely add comments into the middle of a line or along multiple lines using command substitution. This [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522631/how-to-put-a-line-comment-for-a-multi-line-command#12797512) should show you how to safely add comments.

To go off your example it would look like this:

```
step 1 `#1st comment` \
step 2 `#2nd comment` \
step 3 `#3rd comment` \
step 4 --some_options `#4th comment` --additional_options `#5th comment` --final_options `#6th comment`
```

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1456019) which should help you. Is there any reason this has to be copied and pasted into PuTTY specifically? One solution would be to use `scp` or some other method to transfer the shell script file to your remote machine and then execute the script there.

Comment: Wow, I like it but it certainly scares me at my current novice level. Thank you for the links to those other questions.